# What is the reason for 'Unable to resolve substream' error in ADTF?

Tags: adtf, adtf3

I'm having the following problem when trying to setup Substream Assembler filter with Substream Selector:
[image]

I have the following basic setup in the ADTF tool:
[image]

The input to Substream Assembly is simply a dummy filter, generating some random data and sending it to the output pin.

Substream assembly is supposed to take multiple inputs from the usual, non-substream returning filters and transform it into a substreams, if I understand it correctly, and then we can extract them with Substream Selector.

I cannot understand where this warning/error is coming from. Do you have any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning seems to be just a bug, maybe based on initialization order issues (egg-chicken-issue).

As you can see above the Substream Selector, samples are processed. Just connect for example a Qt5 Media Description Display to the Substream Selector and you will see the values of P_tInt32.

If you use an invalid name, for example P_something, you will get the warning twice and no data. So yes, you can just ignore the warning during startup, everything is fine and will be fixed in upcoming releases.